# python ordered dict with duplicates keys

Tags: python, data-structures, dictionary, duplicates

I'm trying to write some python functions to generate a batch of input files, in which there is, for instance, this block:

```
***behavior
**energy_phase_1
ef_v 10
**energy_phase_2
ef_v 7.
```

So far i was using collections.OrderedDict, because order matters in this kind of input file). For instance,if there are two simulations in my batch:

```
inp_dict['***behavior'] = [ '', '']
inp_dict['**energy_phase_1'] = [ '', '']
inp_dict['**ef_v'] = [ '10', '20']
inp_dict['**energy_phase_2'] = [ '', '']
inp_dict['**ef_v'] = [ '7', '14']
```

And to write the file I would just do something like:

```
for s , n in enumerate(sim_list):
    ......some code...
    inp_file.write(' '.join([ key, val[s], '\n' for key, val in inp_dict.items]))
```

But as you can see, this is not enough, since it there are duplicates key in the dict.

So my question is: is there an ordered dict that allows for duplicate keys? For instance, if there exists dict['key']=1 and dict['key']=2, first call would return 1 and second 2?

Or, is there some clever and simple way to achieve want I want?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you keep dict['key'] as an array, for example [1,2]? Then you can have multiple values for one key rather than multiple keys with different values.

Comment: Because dict['key'] is already an array, since I have inp_dict['**ef_v'] = [ value for sim 1 = '10', value for sim2= '20'], as well as inp_dict['**ef_v'] = [ value for sim 1 = '7', value for sim2= '14'], whihc are aprt of different *** blocks.

Comment: If one would really want, one could implement a dict-like object that works as described. You'd probably subclass the ABC `collections.Mapping` or `collections.MutableMapping`, internally store the multi-values as a dict of lists and maintain indices to the last returned element of each list. However, returning different things on key lookup feels quite ill-defined and certainly breaks with standard expectations of users. I strongly recommend to rethink the idea. Are these keys really the same if you have different values? Could you make a simple dict of lists and iterate the returned list?

Answer (score 4):

The concept of *duplicate key* goes against the concept of dict.

If you need to maintain order **and** have duplicate keys I'd say you need to use another data structure. One possible solution would be using a list of tuples. Something like the following:

```
inp = list()

# Define your input as a list of tuples instead of as a dict

inp.append(('***behavior', ('', '')))
inp.append(('**energy_phase_1', ('', '')))
inp.append(('**ef_v', ('10', '20')))
inp.append(('**energy_phase_2', ('', '')))
inp.append(('**ef_v', ('7', '14')))

# You can have duplicate keys on the list and the order is preserved

output = "\n".join(["{key} {val}".format(key=t[0], val=t[1][0]).strip() for t in inp])
```

In this case the `output` variable would contain:

```
***behavior
**energy_phase_1
**ef_v 10
**energy_phase_2
**ef_v 7
```

If you need to access values by key (a dict-like functionality) you could use something like this:

```
def get_key_values(inp, key):

    filtr_by_key = filter(lambda t: True if t[0] == key else False, inp)
    return filtr_by_key

ef_v_values = get_key_values(inp, "**ef_v")
```

In this case the `ef_v_values` would contain only the values associated with the key `**ef_v`:

```
[('**ef_v', ('10', '20')), ('**ef_v', ('7', '14'))]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I know this goes against the dict philosophy, but it feels like something is lacking between the dict and the tuple objects. I don't quite get the second example at the moment, but maybe the night will make it clearer.

Comment: The second example is just a helper function in case you needed to access simulation results contained in *inp* by key (something that in a dict would be straightforward: inp[key]). The real "answer" to your question is only the first part :)